# How to properly index time (IndexError problem)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time, signals

I am currently working on a program (electric simulations of RAM to keep it simple) that requires two functions of t (time) that are then reused in the rest of the code.

The problem I have is that I need to return a value of calculated voltage for a given time (for example 0.9 sec). The voltage itself is calculated based on a simple math formula being applied to a tension ramp I have created using signal.sawtooth. The ramp of course is depending on a time array I have created using linspace.

`temps = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)`

`Vrampe=1.6*signal.sawtooth( 2*np.pi*freq*temps,0.5)` #here I create tension ramp, frequency is set to 1/3

then the function that causes problem:

```
def Vox(t):
    calcul_vox=np.linspace(0,3,100)
    for i in range(len(calcul_vox)):
        calcul_vox[i]=(Vrampe[i]/((1+R*Gon*P)*d)) #R=300Ohms, Gon=0.00085 Siemens, P=1, d=4.5-10^-10
    return calcul_vox[t] #here I don't know how to index the time
```

it gives me the error:

"IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

But I know after looking on the web that I can't index arrays with floats, but the problem is also that I later call the function in other functions because I need the calculated values.

So please I would like to know it there is a way to index time, or if I need to use another method ? I have thought of normalizing the time array but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Vrampe is not a list or any kind of object that can be indexed - it's a float (numpy.float64)

Comment: Well actually Vrampe is an array of floats generated by signal.sawtooth : it has the same lenght as temps (the time array)

Comment: quick glance, you are changing calcul_vox (which is initially a np.linspace) in the loop, that is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing a np.linspace object in the loop. As a start, I would change your code as follows:

```
def Vox(t):
    calcul_vox = []
    for i in range(len(np.linspace(0, 3, 100)):
        # R=300Ohms, Gon=0.00085 Siemens, P=1, d=4.5-10^-10
        calcul_vox.append(Vrampe[i]/((1+R*Gon*P)*d)) 

    # here I don't know how to index the time
    return calcul_vox[t]
```

Here I assume t is an integer!